# Google Drive maxResults ignored when using a query string in a Files#list request

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to retrieve the files of a certain folder and paginate the results.

The query looks like:

- request: Files#List
- maxResults: 1
- q: 'root' in parents

If I have 2 documents in my root folder, I will receive the 2 results instead of 1.
There won't be any *nextPageToken* or *nextLink*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this and couldn't reproduce the behavior you're reporting.  My query is:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='root'+in+parents&maxResults=2
```

And I get exactly 2 file resources back, while also getting a nextPageToken and nextLink.